# Mono c# Getting the class

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I am trying to to instance a class and call a function of a c# class using mono with c++.

My code is:

```
mono_config_parse(NULL);
mono_set_assemblies_path("C:\\Users\\Oriorii\\Desktop\\MonoTest\\MonoScripts\\dlls");

MonoDomain* domain = nullptr;
domain = mono_jit_init("MonoScripts");

MonoAssembly* assembly = mono_domain_assembly_open(domain, "CSharp.dll"); // works
MonoImage* image = mono_assembly_get_image(assembly); // works

mono_jit_exec(domain, assembly, argc, argv); 

MonoClass* klass = mono_class_from_name(image, nullptr, "Class1"); // fails


MonoMethodDesc* ctorDesc = mono_method_desc_new("Class1:Class1()", false); // works
MonoMethod* ctorMethod = mono_method_desc_search_in_class(ctorDesc, klass); // fails because klass is nullptr


MonoMethodDesc* doDesc = mono_method_desc_new("Class1::PrintTest()", false); // works
MonoMethod* doMethod = mono_method_desc_search_in_class(doDesc, klass); // fails because klass is nullptr


mono_jit_cleanup(domain);
```

And my c# is:

```
using System;

public class Class1
{
    public void PrintTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HELLO!!");
    }
}
```

The problem comes in this line 'MonoClass* klass = mono_class_from_name(image, nullptr, "Class1");' that this function returns nullptr but the next line where I do 'MonoMethodDesc* ctorDesc = mono_method_desc_new("Class1:Class1()", false);' it does not return nullptr. So I do not understand what's happening.

I also tried to put the c# class into a namespace but it happens the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it as

```
MonoClass* klass = mono_class_from_name(image, "", "Class1");
```

instead. That has worked for me.

Also, if you need to create a class instance without needing to pass parameters to the constructor, you can use

```
MonoObject *ClassInstance = mono_object_new(domain, klass);
mono_runtime_object_init(ClassInstance);
```

The way that you are looking for the constructor will not work since you are using "Class1:Class1()". Instead, it should be "Class1:.ctor()". (Please note that there is a period in front of ctor.)